# Does the web browser stylesheet override all other CSS styles?

Tags: css, html, browser, stylesheet

I just wanted to know, does the web browser style sheet override all other CSS styles or is that not true?

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific hierarchy in css stylesheets. Normally your custom styles.css should override all the webbrowser styles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does,as long as you use the correct path's

Or specify for which one are you talking about e.g. the one that you will use to edit or something else?

Answer (score 0):

That is false.  You can have outside style sheets linked and have inner style code and they will both work.  But if there is content that is styled in both outer and inner CSS, then inner CSS will override outer CSS linked pages.

Comment: so would you say it overrides like the.. web browser presentation defaults?

Comment: @ChrisHapeshis Let's say if you have content styled in the inner <style></style> tags, and the content already is styled in a separate, linked CSS code from another website.  The inner CSS code will override all other linked CSS pages.  Hope that helped.  Feel free to reply if you need some more clarification.  Thanks

Comment: @ChrisHapeshis No problem!  Always like to help the best I can

Comment: I've not really used the id attribute, does it have to be unique on the page or across all pages on a website?